# What is the fast and elegant way to find probabilities of large amount of variables using histogram of probabilities in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have 2 histograms of probabilities: one for normal work of a machine and other for abnormal work.
Each histogram has M bins, and I have N values for which I want to know the probabilities. Histogram is represented in code with 2 lists: list with the probability for a value to be in this segment, list of histogram edges, ordered in ascending order. I need to find to what segment element belongs and print it's probability according to histogram. Histograms do not intersect.

```
normal_histogram = [0.5, 0.5]
normal_edges_of_histogram = [0,1.5,3]

abnormal_hist = [0.6, 0.4]
abnormal_edges = [5,7,9]
```

Obviously iterating over every value and comparing it with edges of histogram would give me time complexity of O(N*M). I would like to reduce that value but I dont know what is the best way to do it. Because I can't change number of elements N I should focus on M. May be implementing a binary search on a list of edges would be better. Or turning lists of edges into hash tables to get time complexity of a search O(1). Or may be there are better way to represent a histogram in code (I don't need graphical representation like matplotlib)

Example of a code:

```
normal_histogram = [0.5, 0.5]
normal_edges_of_histogram = [0,1.5,3]

abnormal_hist = [0.6, 0.4]
abnormal_edges = [5,7,9]

values = [5,1,78,2,6,8,2,9,0]

#bad time complexity
for x in values:
  l_edge = 0
  r_edge = l_edge+1
  prob = 0
  while right_edge <= len(normal_edges_of_histogram)-1:
    if normal_edges_of_histogram[l_edge] <= x <= normal_edges_of_histogram[r_edge]
      prob = normal_histogram[l_edge]
      break
    elif abnormal_edges[l_edge] <= x <= abnormal_edges[r_edge]
      prob = abnormal_hist[l_edge]
      break
    l_edge += 1
    r_edge += 1
  print(prob)
```

Output can be list of probabilities for each element like this

```
answer = [0.6, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Comment: If the edges are always evenly spaced like the examples, then you can just calculate the appropriate bin.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, Yes, the edges are always evenly spaced. Also i forgot to mention that if a variable for this example is 7 the probability is 0.6.